# Loopback: Send extra key/value pairs in response

Tags: loopbackjs

I have searched through the docs but am unable to find how I can add additional data to my json responses.

Lets say I am executing a GET call to /api/customers

I would like each customer to return the field "address" which is a concatenation of the street_name and door_number properties defined in the Customer model.

So somewhere I need to define "address" = this.street_name + ' ' + this.door_number and add this to the response. Can someone point me to an example of this?

UPDATE

I have tried to add this to customer.js

```
'use strict';
const app = require('../../server/server');

module.exports = function(Customer) {

  const query = "SELECT *, CONCAT( door_number|| ' ' || street_name) as address from my_customer_table";

  app.dataSources.mysqlIDs.connector.query(query, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    return res;
  });
};
```

UPDATE 2:

If I do a console log on res:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 5,
    ...
    address: '491 Hondsruglaan' 
  },
  RowDataPacket {...
  }
]
```

When I use the pipe characters in the SQL query address will show as:

```
address: '1'
```

However the address field is not yet reflected in the API response. All the fields are there, but not address. It seems that the code is only executed when the app is booted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an elegant solution in my opinion:

```js
// customer.js

module.exports = function(Customer) {
  Customer.afterRemote('find', function(context, customers, next) {
    context.result.forEach(customer => {
      customer.address = customer.street_name + ' ' + customer.door_number
    })
    
    next()
  })
}
```

Comment: I have to agree with this. This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

const query = `SELECT *, CONCAT( door_number|| ' ' || street_name) as address from customer`

Here Iam using postgresql database

`loopback.dataSources.postgres.connector.query(query, (err, res) => {
     return cb(err, res);
});`

Only by executing native query you can achieve concatenation two columns in response, loopback's default method doesnt support

Comment: See my question. I have tried to add the code to customer.js but the new address field is not yet reflecting in the response. Any idea?

Comment: also, I think the pipe characters in the SQL query have to be replaced with comma's.

Comment: Will you please send the res from executing this code.And I dont think so there is any difference in replacing those pipe characters.

Comment: see my updated question. With pipe characters address is reflected as '1'. But the main point now is that the address field is not seen in the api responses, for example in /explorer.